# Get unique point pairs

Tags: matlab

I am computing a distance function from a set of points to choose points with a certain tolerance d of a distance x and have written this code:

```
function pts_pairs = donut_neighbor(pts,x,d)
% Matrix of pts repeated for the total number of points 
temp_pts1 = repmat(pts,size(pts,1),1);
% Matrix of pts where each row is repeated total number of point times
% Uses kronecker product which repeats all the elements 
temp_pts2 = kron(pts,ones(size(pts,1),1));
% Compute the distance between the matrices 
dist = sqrt((temp_pts1(:,1)-temp_pts2(:,1)).^2 + (temp_pts1(:,2)-temp_pts2(:,2)).^2);
% Get indices of the point pairs in the donut
ind = dist > (x-d/2) & dist < (x+d/2);
% output point coordinates of the point pairs
pts_pairs = [temp_pts1(ind,:) temp_pts2(ind,:)];
```

Now I want to get only the unique point pairs. So for my code, the point pair A-B will be counted twice as A-B and B-A but I want only the pair A-B to be counted (other pair to be erased). Any easy way to go about it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example with input and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
pts_pairs =

     1     2
     1     3
     3     4
     2     1
     3     1
     4     5
```

For example, if 1 is related to 2, and 2 is related to 1, you want to keep only one ocurrence. You could do something like this:

```
unique(sort(pts_pairs, 2), 'rows')
```

Which gives:

```
ans =

     1     2
     1     3
     3     4
     4     5
```